# How to read an excel file with rows as columns and columns as rows with Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, data-science

I have the following problem: I want to read an Excel file that was changed in its original form, using columns as rows and rows as columns (in this way the size of the excel file is reduced a lot, initially it sized around ~80MB). Down to 7 MB.

The point is that: initially, as it was a normal Excel, Pandas could read it easily, but now that it has changed, I don't know what form it should have to read it like that.

I tried using ".transpose()" on the DataFrame but it doesn't look like it should, it doesn't look like I was reading it normally.

Any solution?, Thanks.

I try with the method ".transpose()" in the DF, but it's not works like I expecting.

Comment: Please create a [reprex], explaining whty `.tranpose()` is not working as you expect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transpose() function to transpose the DataFrame after reading the Excel file.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
df_transposed = df.transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer helps you, but If your Excel file has been transformed in such a way that the columns and rows are swapped (columns as rows and rows as columns), and it's not being read correctly using Pandas' .transpose() method, you can try a different approach to read and transform the data correctly.

please do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')
```

Transpose the DataFrame to swap rows and columns:

```
# Transpose the DataFrame
df_transposed = df.transpose()
```

if the columns and rows are not swapped please put a few records that I will see, and find solutions.